# Understanding different forms of recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to practice some recursive functions in haskell. The following random functions show some different forms of recursions and iterations. I have problems understanding which form of recursion or iteration is connected to a function. I know the recursion forms tail recursion, linear recursion and tree recursion and the regular iteration. Is there any strategy to assign one of the four different forms i know every function?

```
f1 x y z = if x > y then f1 (x+2) (y-1) z else y

f2 x y z = if z /= 0 then y + x + f2 (x-1) (y-1) (z-2) else 1

f3 x y z = if y < 0 then True
else (f3 (f3 (x-2) (y-4) (z-6)) (4*y) (z-2)) + (f3 6 (y-2) (z*2))

f4 x y z = if z > 0 then (f4 (x-y) (y+1) (x-z)) + (f4 2 x z) else y+x- 
(2*z)
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking here. I don't see different "forms" of recursion here - whatever that would mean - they're all just `if` statements which recurse in one case and otherwise calculate a result directly. (And all imo would be more readable with guards rather than an `if` statement.)

Comment: All iteration is recursion in Haskell. Linear vs tree recursion is a feature of the funtion in question, and can be decided even at a syntactic level. Tail recursion is an implementation question, for which I do not believe GHC provides any guarantees, though it will often do so if given suitable input. Beyond that, I am also unsure what you're asking.

Comment: @moonGoose Tail-call *optimization* is a implementation question; `f1` is tail-recursive no matter how the function is evaluated.

Comment: @Napkin: I'd call those different *recursion schemes*. And is there a strategy for picking a recursion scheme? Isn't this sort of like asking if there's a strategy for problem solving in general?

Answer (score 2):

The strategy is to look at how the return value of each recursive call is used:

- In `f1`, the return value is itself returned immediately
- In `f2`, the return value of a *single* recursive call is used to compute the return value of the original call.
- In `f3` and `f4`, the return values of *multiple* recursive calls are used to compute the return value of the original call.

(The fact that you need to make a recursive call to `f3` in order to compute an argument for *another* recursive call doesn't, I think, affect any classification you are asked to make.)